# Migration from 1.9.x to Magento 2.3.x issue

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, php, migration

I try to migrate data from my old Magento store 1.9.3.10 to the new Magento 2.3.2 but when I run:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --auto -r vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.10/config.xml
```

I have the following output:

```
[2019-07-01 08:39:17][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_type is not mapped in record attribute_id=189
[2019-07-01 08:39:17][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: backend_model. Error: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_grid_columns is not mapped in record attribute_id=191
[2019-07-01 08:39:17][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_columns is not mapped in record attribute_id=192
[2019-07-01 08:39:17][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: backend_model. Error: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_dropdown_blocks is not mapped in record attribute_id=193
[2019-07-01 08:39:17][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_categorylabel is not mapped in record attribute_id=194
[2019-07-01 08:39:17][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class giftcard/adminhtml_system_config_source_giftcard_type is not mapped in record attribute_id=204
[2019-07-01 08:39:17][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: catalog_eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input_renderer. Error: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_helper_grid_columns is not mapped in record attribute_id=191
[2019-07-01 08:39:17][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: catalog_eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input_renderer. Error: Class ultramegamenu/category_attribute_helper_dropdown_blocks is not mapped in record attribute_id=193
[2019-07-01 08:39:17][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_entity_type. Field: entity_model. Error: Class xpayment-eav/xpayment is not mapped in record entity_type_id=9
```

What I can do?

Thank you

Comment: I also want to do the same thing, can I get documentation? @Robert

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this in your `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml`. Ensure that `class-map.xml` is specified correctly in `config.xml`

```
<rename>
        <from>ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_type</from>
        <to></to>
</rename>
```

Similarly, you can rename all the classes. You can too exclude those integrity constraint warnings

```
php bin/magento migrate:data -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.10/config.xml
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer, can you please explain me a little more what is mean to: ensure that class-map.xml is specified correctly in config.xml ???

Comment: Those warnings are due to integrity violations. You can ignore those too. So class_map.xml can be used to ignore the class mappings when the class mappings are not available in Magento 2. Are you getting any errors while performing migration.

Comment: thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that the Migration from Magento1 to Magento2 relies heavily on the vanilla setup. It seems that you have customized some EAV Attributes which aren't mapped in your new Magento2 instance.

You can either use `-a` for the CLI Migration command or try to map those fields manually in the respective Migration Folder in your root directory, see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html