# Magento2 - Incompatibility in data (magento miration error)

Tags: magento2, migration

here is the error i am getting during migration

> [2020-02-26 07:12:10][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source
>   document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class
>   eav/entity_attribute_source_custom is not mapped in record
>   attribute_id=563

I tried to use the below code in class-map.xml but not worked. and I also chaned the class-map.xml.dist to class-map.xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- /** * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details. */ -->

<classmap xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../class-map.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<rename>

<from>eav/entity_attribute_source_custom </from>

<to>Afg\Customerattribute\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Useurterm</to>

</rename>

</classmap>
```

the error I am getting after change the name of `class-map.xml` is

> Invalid map filename

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280281/migration-from-1-9-x-to-magento-2-3-x-issue

Comment: i am trying to follow above link

Comment: Please refer this link :- https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/243

Comment: mohit I am trying to intergrate M1 custom customer attribute with M2.... How can i Data of M1 attribute in M2 I have already made M2 customer attribute

Comment: My M2 attribute has same attribute code as M1 attribute code

Comment: @MohitPatel M1 attribute whole data in M2 with M2 attribute..... I had done data migration once ignoring the attribute error